# Can you run PHPUnit tests from a script?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a PHP deployment script that I want to run PHPUnit tests first, and stop if the tests fail. I've been googling this a lot, and it's very hard to find documentation on running unit tests from php, rather than from the command line tool.

For the newest version of PHPUnit, can you do something like:

```
$unit_tests = new PHPUnit('my_tests_dir');
$passed = $unit_tests->run();
```

Preferably a solution that doesn't require me to manually specify each test suite.

Comment: PHPUnit ships with source. You can [take a look into the testrunner](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php) it contains the code to run phpunit from a script.

Comment: Good hint! Is there any pre-implemented way to gather up all of my test suites to be run?

Comment: I'm a little surprised this isn't a very common thing to do. Is there a better way to run all of your unit tests automatically when doing something like deploying?

Comment: of course it is, just run: phpunit ./dir/to/your/tests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
$phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner;

try {
    $test_results = $phpunit->dorun($phpunit->getTest(__DIR__, '', 'Test.php'));
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    die ("Unit tests failed.");
}
```

Comment: in the sample above, how can we get the text report details from the $test_results object?

Comment: When I tested I only got an exception is if there was  a problem with the setup or the tests, not if a unit test failed, so `$test_results` is available even on test failures.

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way to do this is by instantiating object of class PHPUnit_TextUI_Command.

So here is an example:

```
require '/usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

function dummy($input)
{
   return '';
}

//Prevent PHPUnit from outputing anything
ob_start('dummy');

//Run PHPUnit and log results to results.xml in junit format
$command = new PHPUnit_TextUI_Command;
$command->run(array('phpunit', '--log-junit', 'results.xml', 'PHPUnitTest.php'),
              true);

ob_end_clean();
```

This way the results will be logged in results.xml file in junit format that can be parsed. If you need a different format you can check the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html). Also you can add more options by changing the array passed to run method.

Answer (score 3):

working with PHPUnit 7.5:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite;

$test = new TestSuite();
$test->addTestSuite(MyTest::class);
$result = $test->run();
```

and $result object contains lot of usefull data:

```
$result->errors()
$result->failures
$result->wasSuccessful()
```

etc...

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I can use this in a scratch or interview environment where I don't know where all the files are located and can instead run tests directly on classes I have access to, without the command line. I found some useful documentation on these classes here: https://damienflament.github.io/phpunit-api-docs/6.4/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.html#method_failures

Answer (score 2):

Solution for PHP7 & phpunit ^7

```php
use PHPUnit\TextUI\Command;

$command = new Command();
$command->run(['phpunit', 'tests']);
```

Does the same effect as CLI command:

```sh
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests
```

Comment: how to get the output? like I imagine the reason to run phpunit from code is to then send an email or soemthing with "x failed, y passed" obviously

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like PHPUnit has any built-in configuration to prevent it from dumping its output directly into the response (at least not as of PHPUnit 5.7).

So, I used `ob_start` to shunt output to a variable, and set the third argument of `doRun` to `false` to prevent PHPUnit from halting the script:

```
<?php

$suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite();
$suite->addTestSuite('App\Tests\DatabaseTests');

// Shunt output of PHPUnit to a variable
ob_start();
$runner = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner;
$runner->doRun($suite, [], false);
$result = ob_get_clean();

// Print the output of PHPUnit wherever you want
print_r($result);
```