# Binding Laravel phpunit tests to routes

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm building a RESTful API using Laravel 5.1. I wrote functional tests using the default phpunit came with the package. I'm able to run the tests from command line with  `phpunit` command.

I want to create a route called `/tests`, and bind it to the phpunit tests. So after I deploy the api to the server, I should get the test results when I make a `GET` request to `http://api.mysite.com/test`.

Is that possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to run the tests on your production server?

Comment: Its for this API only, I need to show the functional tests that are running to the people I'll demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a route like this:

```
Route::get('tests', array(function () {
 $phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner;

    try {
        $test_results = $phpunit->dorun($phpunit->getTest(__DIR__, '', 'Test.php'));
    } catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
        print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        die ("Unit tests failed.");
    }
}));
```

Taken from similar question: [Can you run PHPUnit tests from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302466/can-you-run-phpunit-tests-from-a-script)