# Phpunit tests from code gives exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've got this code in my route (just to get it to work).

```
Route::get('/', function () {
$phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner;
try {
    $test_results = $phpunit->dorun($phpunit->getTest('/var/www/cms/tests/', '', 'Test.php'));
    dd($test_results);
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    die ("Unit tests failed.");
}
});
```

The code example to run a test from code can be found here: 
[Can you run PHPUnit tests from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302466/can-you-run-phpunit-tests-from-a-script)

But when I run this I'm getting the error: **Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed**

I can't figure out what is causing this error.

Answer (score 5):

See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.backupGlobals

```
You can turn off this, in config, example:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<phpunit bootstrap="application/tests/bootstrap.php" backupGlobals="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="TestSuite">
            <directory>application/tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed the issue, but it's not a stable fix and I'd like to know some better solution. For now I'll post this as answer.

In: **/vendor/sebastian/global-state/src/Snapshot.php** line **313**

replace this line:

```
$this->globalVariables[$key] = unserialize(serialize($GLOBALS[$key]));
```

With:

```
$this->globalVariables[$key] = $GLOBALS[$key];
```

I find this line very weird. The function is just storing globals and I have no idea why it would serialize the data while immediately unserialize it.

Comment: That issue is fixed in newer versions of that library

Comment: Why this recent version phpunit still error, not fixed yet.

Comment: Looks like it's not fixed yet, see: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/global-state/blob/master/src/Snapshot.php

Comment: `unserialize(serialize($foo))` is a trick that perform a "deep clone" (or recursive clone if you prefer). Native clone command in PHP will preserve references to classes' internal objects.  while this trick create new instances with identical properties.

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem. After `composer update filp/whoops` problem was solved.