# Phpunit - printing results with PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter?

Tags: phpunit

I have a situation where i am calling the PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner directly

```
try {
error_log('phpunit');
$phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner();
$test_results = $phpunit->dorun($phpunit->getTest(__DIR__.'/../tests', '', 'Test.php'));
error_log($test_results->count().' '.$test_results->failureCount());
} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
error_log("Unit tests failed.");
}
```

as per the answer in this thread [Can you run PHPUnit tests from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302466/can-you-run-phpunit-tests-from-a-script)

In my case, I'd like to see the number and details if the tests ran, and display them to the user. I've updated the code to set the printer object

```
try {
error_log('phpunit');

$phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner();
// set the printer
$resultPrinter = new PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter();
$phpunit->setPrinter($resultPrinter);

$test_results = $phpunit->dorun($phpunit->getTest(__DIR__.'/../tests', '', 'Test.php'));
error_log($test_results->count().' '.$test_results->failureCount());
// print results returns nothing?
$resultPrinter->printResult($test_results);
$resultPrinter->flush();

} catch (PHPUnit_Framework_Exception $e) {
print $e->getMessage() . "\n";
error_log("Unit tests failed.");
}
```

but nothing appears in my log. Can someone advise how i can capture and display the output from the PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter?

Comment: Nothing at all appears in your log? For both cases (w/ or w/o exception) `error_log` is called according to the code. So at leas something should appear (if not error handling is preventing it).

Comment: @emeraldjava The provided code works and indeed outputs two lines into `stderr` as well as test run into `stdout`.
Are you expecting to get output into console?
If yes, then apparently something's wrong in code that is left outside or `PHP` or `PHPunit` configuration.
If no, then you probably would like to specifically provide the expected `$out` param to the `Printer` constructor.
P.S. `printResult` is already called inside the 'doRun' function, so no need to call it explicitly.