# Can I run PHPUnit tests from a PHP script?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302466/can-you-run-phpunit-tests-from-a-script) with no success.

I tried

```php
$test = new \PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite();
$test->addTestSuite(Tester::class);
$result = $test->run();
```

and i got error that `index '_SERVER' is undefined on line 26 of (PHPUnit\Util\Filter file)` so I changed that line from `$GLOBALS['_SERVER']['SCRIPT_NAME']` to use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`;

Now I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: Argument #1 (No
>   Value) of PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::addTestSuite() must be a class
>   name or object /var/www/html/test/index.php:19 thrown in
>   /var/www/html/test/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/InvalidArgumentHelper.php on line 23

if I `var_dump(Tester::class)` it outputs `string(6) "Tester"`, so I know that `Tester` class is valid.

---

It looks like PHPUnit is supposed to be run from command line. But I'm hoping I can run from a PHP script instead.

Comment: Did you tried best answer from link  you mentioned `$phpunit = new PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner; $phpunit->dorun(...);` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you run PHPUnit tests from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302466/can-you-run-phpunit-tests-from-a-script)

Comment: I didn't really pay it any mind, since I was trying version 8 of PHPUnit. I could have tried the v8 version `PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner`, but `addTestSweet` still is giving me a fatal error, thus I'm not able to pass the `TestSuite` object to the `TestRunner` constructor.

Comment: I believe this is still the entry point for phpunit8 https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/d1a4afef8b49b3202411c7648e380e0913e1c265/src/TextUI/Command.php#L158 you might want to use it as a start point for your own starter code (well, you might better like consequent `run()` method)